# Applying PRIMARY KEY constraint in CockroachDB - multiple primary keys error

Tags: constraints, primary-key, cockroachdb

I have created a table in CRDB without having any PRIMARY KEY and populated my data into the table.

Now that the table is created and populated with data I want to apply a constraint to make the first column as PRIMARY KEY. But I get an error:

The constraint is:

```
ALTER TABLE “MyDB”.“SALES” ADD CONSTRAINT “SALES_PK” PRIMARY KEY (“S_ID”);
```

and the error is:

```
pq: multiple primary keys for table “SALES” are not allowed.
```

I think there reason is in CRDB if no PRIMARY KEY is mentioned, CRDB automatically will assign a PRIMARY KEY to the table named: `rowid`.

How can I see PRIMARY KEY in a table in CRDB?
and
How can I Make the column I want as PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, CockroachDB has the limitation that you cannot modify the primary key of a table after it is created. If you create a table without a primary key, under the hood an invisible `rowid` column will be created for you and set as the primary key.

You will have to recreate your table with a primary key set in the `CREATE TABLE` expression.

Comment: [Documentation](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/primary-key.html) for further reading.

Comment: In this [doc](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v23.1/alter-table#changing-primary-keys-with-add-constraint-primary-key), it says "You can use ADD CONSTRAINT ... PRIMARY KEY to add a primary key to an existing table if one of the following is true...No primary key was explicitly defined at table creation. In this case, the table is created with a default primary key on rowid. Using ADD CONSTRAINT ... PRIMARY KEY drops the default primary key and replaces it with a new primary key"

Answer (score 1):

You can now do it. You just have to remove the old constraint that was created on the implicit `rowid` unique key within a transaction.

In your example

```
BEGIN;
  ALTER TABLE “MyDB”.“SALES” DROP CONSTRAINT “SALES_PKEY”;
  ALTER TABLE “MyDB”.“SALES” ADD CONSTRAINT “SALES_PK” PRIMARY KEY (“S_ID”);
COMMIT;
```

I believe the `rowid` constraint is named `[table_name]_pkey` which is why it's `SALES_PKEY` in the above example. You can verify by running `SHOW CONSTRAINTS FROM SALES`